# WPF CheckBox with Rounded Corners

Tags: wpf, checkbox

Is it possible to style a WPF checkbox to have rounded corners by modifying a custom style? If so, how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way that I know

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="134,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}"/>
```

resource dictioanry

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero">
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border Background="#FFAEB3B9" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
                            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </BulletDecorator>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The line starting with `Microsoft_Windows_Themes:BulletChrome` is a complete red-no-compile zone for me, what does that require?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Its possible.

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx) , you can get the full style for an existing checkBox, and it appears that the Border isn't drawn by a Decorator. So just change this section in your style and apply it.

```
<Border x:Name="Border"
                Width="13"
                Height="13"
 <!--Here-->        CornerRadius="0"
                BorderThickness="1">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
```

Comment: Lol, or look at the other answer for the full copy. :-)